# Programmatically calling siri shortcut from app

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts

I'm currently planning an iOS app that makes use of NFC tags and iOS shortcuts. Idea is that once a NFC tag has been scanned, a shortcut is triggered that executes certain commands and then opens the app. That part shouldn't be an issue, since as far as I understand, one can write the shortcut name into the NFC tag and iOS will then run the shortcut (at least with the newest iPhones).

Once I remove the phone from then NFC tag another shortcut should be executed (iPhone would rest on the sticker for a while and wont enter sleeping mode). Now this is where I'm not sure if that possible. I can detect when the NFC tag is out of reach/cant be read with my app (which is still open when the phone is removed from the NFC tag), but am I able to then call a shortcut once I register the NFC tag is out of reach?

So to sum up the question: can I programmatically call an iOS shortcut from my own app without the user pressing any button on the phone? If not, is it possible when the user presses a button in the app (without leaving the app or launching siri)

Answer (score -1):

From what I have been able to figure out, the only way to programmatically trigger a Siri shortcut is using deeplinks. I followed [this article](https://medium.com/swift2go/running-other-apps-siri-shortcuts-through-deeplinks-in-swift-85e022576332) to create an open a URL that runs a certain Siri shortcut. The 2 caveats are that the app opening the URL, your app, must be in the foreground, and the shortcuts app is opened.